# Postfix smtp error 450 (failed to add recipient)

Tags: linux, postfix, roundcube

I have debian server with postfix and roundcube. After an attack we are on 2 blacklists, but I don't think that this is the main problem. I can't send mail to any address. I tried to find the cause...I checked var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf and resolv.etc and they're the same with this content:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver localhost
```

In var/log/mail.err I found:

```
cyrus/imap[25452]: DBERROR: opening /var/lib/cyrus/user/m/marcel@mydomain.com.seen: cyrusdb error
cyrus/imap[25452]: DBERROR: skiplist recovery /var/lib/cyrus/user/m/marcel@mydomain.com.seen: ADD at 1FC0 exists
```

When I try to send email from roundcube, I get the message from title. When I send it within opera or any other mail client, It gives nothing, but email is'nt sended.
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide a log when you actually try to send a message? mail.log instead of mail.err might include more info. The cyrus error is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

> `DBERROR: opening /var/lib/cyrus/user/m/marcel@mydomain.com.seen: cyrusdb error`
>   `DBERROR: skiplist recovery
>   /var/lib/cyrus/user/m/marcel@mydomain.com.seen: ADD at 1FC0 exists`

It means that the skiplist file is corrupted. As you can see, there is something wrong at `1FC0`. Truncate the file at this point, the users mail read state will be valid up to the point of corruption.

First, convert the hex to decimal:

```
$ echo "ibase=16;1FC0" | bc
8128
```

Then, using `dd` command to truncate the file:

```
# dd if=marcel@mydomain.com.seen of=marcel@mydomain.com.seen.fixed bs=1 count=8128
# mv marcel@mydomain.com.seen marcel@mydomain.com.seen.corrupt
# mv marcel@mydomain.com.seen.fixed marcel@mydomain.com.seen
```

Source: https://sysadm.equoria.com/index.php/Cyrus_Mailbox_Reconstruction_(OS_X)

Answer (score 0):

#### /etc/resolv.conf

This file defines which name servers to use.It gives access to the DNS(Domain Name System).
Point your nameserver to the correct IP address see more at http://theos.in/desktop-linux/resolve-conf-linux-example/.
Here your resolv.conf is pointing to the loopback address that is why your mails are  not sending.
If your DNS is managed by a DNS hosting service then point your nameserver to that address.

Comment: I change the loopback address to DNS server provided by my hosting service provider, but nothing changed. Still the same error message. Do I have to restart something after modyfying resolv.conf?

Comment: yes you have to restart bind after that i.e. run:- service named restart.